# AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'set_appearance_mode'

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I got a error with the template code. Error:

```
    customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'set_appearance_mode'
```

Code:

```
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

app = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window
app.geometry("400x240")

def button_function():
    print("button pressed")

# Use CTkButton instead of tkinter Button
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="CTkButton", command=button_function)
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)

app.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me here? I use the python version 3.7 in PyCharm.

Comment: Did you name your own file "customtkinter.py"? Do the other customtkinter methods work if you comment out that line?

Comment: Did you try to update customtkinter library? (pip3 install customtkinter --upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine.
Maybe you have an old version of this library.
You can try to update all your modules:

```
pip list --outdated
```

```
pip freeze | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}
```